# How to update browser cache from PHP?

Tags: php, html, caching, optimization

I have a PHP file **get_css.php** which generates CSS code more than 60 KB long. This code does not change very often. I want this code to be cached in user's browser.
Now, when i visit a HTML page several times which includes **get_css.php** url to fetch css, my browser is loading all CSS contents from the server each time i visit the page.

Browsers should get the contents from server only if the CSS code is changed on server side. If the css code is not changed, browser will use the css code from the browser cache.
I cannot use any PHP function which is not allowed in Server Safe Mode.

Is it possible? How can i achieve this?

Comment: Define "not very often": if the CSS changes on your command, you could have it generate a static CSS file and serve that.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: I can not create/Modify a static file because the writing to file is not allowed in PHP Safe Mode.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot force a client to revalidate its cache so easily.

Setting a variable query string to its resource won't play well with proxies, but seems to suffice with browsers. Browsers do tend to only redownload the css file if there's a query string change.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/get_css.php?v=1.2.3">
```

Potentially, you could play with the naming of the CSS, such as add numbers, but this isn't a great alternative.

Comment: Euhm... isn't the correct way to handle cached copies requesting it and getting a 304 Not Modified answer? You can not control the browser's behaviour.

Comment: It's the default behaviour, and true the browser cannot be altered, however, A browser will cache `css_get.php?v=1` and each time it is called, a 304 Not Modified will be produced, however, `css_get.php?v-2` will force a fresh copy to be loaded.

Comment: I doubt that the server will produce a `304` on PHP files, as they are dynamic in nature. Some browsers (IE) will not even *ask* for a copy when they have one in cache (which is wrong in my opinion).

Comment: Yes - the server will not cache the PHP file, but as OP says, the css is stored in the database, so maybe this isn't a bad thing?

Comment: Where do you get that the CSS is in a database?

Comment: @Shamil: My HTML page is static. I mean, if i want to edit the url in <link> tag i have to modify the file all the time.

Comment: @Vin, yes, that is true, and there is no way around editing something to implement the change, OR - you could use `time()` as the query string, but then caching won't be possible. Maybe even play with date strings so that it is cached for month x of year x, or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot control browser behaviour from PHP, but you can use HTTP codes to tell the browser something.

If the CSS is not changed, just reply with a `304 Not Modified` response code:

```
if ($css_has_not_changed && $browser_has_a_copy) {
    http_response_code(304);
} else {
    // regenerate CSS
}
```

This way, the browser *will* ask for the document (which you cannot control), but you tell him to use the cached copy.

Of course this needs testing, as I have now idea how it will work 'the first time' a browser requests the file (perhaps the request headers can tell you more). A quick firebug test reveals that Firefox requests `Cache-Control: no-cache` when it is requesting a fresh copy, and `Cache-Control: max-age=0` when it has cache.

Comment: The flag used in your code $css_has_not_changed checks if the css is changed on server. But It doesn't know that the changed css code is there in user's browser cache or not.

Comment: @Vin that's why I added the piece about the request headers (which you can use in your PHP), use them to see if the browser needs a fresh copy, or has one in its cache already.

Comment: The function http_response_code() is supported by PHP 5 >= 5.4.0 only.

Comment: @Vin the PHP manual of the function gives a lot of examples on how to do it without the function.

Answer (score 0):

add normal GET parameter when you including get_css.php like so

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="get_css.php?v=1">
```

Browser will think that it is new link and will load it again.

and in get_css.php use this **to make browser cache data**

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css");
header('Cache-Control: public');
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', strtotime('+1 year')) . ' GMT');
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");

//echo css here
```

Comment: OP is asking how to force the css to be cached, *not* how to prevent caching.

Comment: The stuff about the GET parameter is completely irrelevant to the question of how to encourage the browser to cache a document. Furthermore, use of the `Expires` header will cause the document to be cached for the indicated *amount of time*, but the OP has specifically requested that "browsers should get the contents from server only if the CSS code is changed on server side".  The header that accomplishes the requested behavior is: `Cache-Control: must-revalidate`.

Answer (score 0):

The browser wants to cache your document by default, but you have to give it enough info to make that possible.  One fairly easy way is to send the `Last-Modified` header, containing the date/time at which your script was last changed.  You'll also need to handle the browser's "revalidation" request correctly by checking the incoming `Last-Modified` date, comparing it to the actual modified date of your script, and returning a `304 Not Modified` response (with an empty response body), if the file is unchanged.

It's also a good idea to be sure that your server isn't "magically" sending any other "no-cache" directives. The easiest way to do this is to send a `Cache-Control` directive that tells the browser exactly what behavior you expect.

[Here](http://palizine.plynt.com/issues/2008Jul/cache-control-attributes/) is a quick explanation of each `Cache-Control` option.

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
<?php
// this must be at the top of your file, no content can be output before it

$modified = filemtime(__FILE__);
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'])) {
  $if_modified_since=strtotime($_SERVER["HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE"]);
  if( $modified > $if_modified_since ) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified');
    exit();
  }
}
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Last-Modified: '.date("r",$modified));

// ... and the rest of your file goes here...
```

The above example was based heavily on the example, and writeup [found here](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/webdesign/provide-last-modified-headers-and-handle-if-modified-since-in-php.html).